# Drupal Conditional page.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal, and I want to load a new page.tpl.php if there is different source in URL like: www.example.com?source=s1

where s1 will load page--p1.tpl.php and s2 will load page--p2.tpl.php

Drupal can load different pages depends on node or node type is it possible to have this kind of functionality.

Currently I have written all if conditions in page.tpl.php to achiever this. But it is looking messy.

Comment: What is `s1` and `s2`?

Comment: These are different sources from where traffic is coming. we want to have different header and footer for each source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use theme suggestion to this , code is given below

```
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
if(arg(0)) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'.  arg(0);
}
```

}

Comment: use your theme name in place of bartik i.e. THEME_NAME_preprocess_page.

write this function in template.php

Comment: Yes I did that. replaced theme name.

Comment: I did some here and there in this hook and its working. Thanks for your help :)